# onChange is not triggering in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-redux, react-component

I use the dropdown in react js app but onChange is not triggering

my code is

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
const options = [
   { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
   { value: 'two', label: 'Two', className: 'myOptionClassName' },

 ];

 class WebDashboardPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {}
  }

 quan = (event)=> {
console.log("Option selected:");
 this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
};

render() {

return(
  <b><Dropdown className="dropdownCss" options={options} onChange={e => 
  this.quan(e.target.value)} /></b>
 );

}
```

when I click the items in dropdown it shows the error

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'quan' of undefined"

I'm a newbie to react 
thanks in advance

Comment: This should be onChange={e => 
  this.quan(e)} or onChange={this.quan}

Comment: It's not working same error is showing

Comment: There is something else do you have quan defined twice anywhere in your component? Because quan is a function in your code but the error says property so you must have quan defined some where else in your component

Comment: @Think-Twice I checked thoroughly there no other quan in my code

Comment: is your project created using create-react-app

Comment: @MurliPrajapati yes I created my app using react-app

Comment: CAN you try with normal function like this.quan = this.quan.bind(this); in constructor and change your function to quan(event){

Comment: @ I tried but in this case, it also gives the same error  
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'quan' of undefined" before entering into the app

Comment: Ok do one thing host your code online and share the link or else share all your code here that’s only way to help you

Comment: plunker link 
https://plnkr.co/edit/7Ay4ZzeqkL2mYihojx62?p=preview

Comment: working for me with pasted code https://codesandbox.io/s/qklz5094z9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with the `react-dropdown` library.  Here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wk424zxqp5) that I've set up and corrected OP's code. It works.

```
import React from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";
import "react-dropdown/style.css";
const options = [
  { value: "one", label: "One" },
  { value: "two", label: "Two", className: "myOptionClassName" }
];
const defaultOption = options[0];
class WebDashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: ""
    };
  }

  quan = value => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown options={options} value={defaultOption} onChange={this.quan} />
    );
  }
}

export default WebDashboardPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just do it this way:

```
<Dropdown className="dropdownCss" options={options} onChange={this.quan} />
```

Try this:

```
 class WebDashboardPage extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { value: '' }
      this.quan = this.quan.bind(this);
      }

     quan(event) {
     console.log("Option selected:");
     this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {

    return(
      <div><Dropdown className="dropdownCss" options={options} onChange={this.quan} /></div>
     );

    }
```

Comment: It's not working same error is showing
any other solution

Comment: I tried your code 

but it shows the error
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'quan' of undefined"
before entering in to the app

Comment: That's mean you forget to add this.quan = this.quan.bind(this); inside constructor

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is with the `react-dropdown` component itself. You'll need to file an issue there.

`react-dropdown` component might not be using `this.props.onChange` somewhere or might be using problematically.

---

Or, it's probably, the component requires `value` state which have not defined?

```
this.state = {
  value: ''
}
```

And was causing the issue?

Comment: I tried all the above but the problem is still exits

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown dependency you are using does not fire onChange with event as argument instead it fires onChange with the selected option.Try changing

```
onChange={e => 
  this.quan(e.target.value)}
```

to

```
onChange={this.quan}
```

and change quan to

```
quan = (selectedOption)=> {
 console.log("Option selected:"+selectedOption.value);
 this.setState({ value: selectedOption.value });
};
```

I have tried it on my machine and it wroks perfectly. Also next important thing is don't put options the way you are doing instead put it on state. my final code is

```
class WebDashboardPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

const options = [
  {
    value: 'one',
    label: 'One'
  }, {
    value: 'two',
    label: 'Two',
    className: 'myOptionClassName'
  }
];

this.state = {options}
}

quan = (selectedOption) => {
console.log("Option selected:" + selectedOption.value);
this.setState({value: selectedOption.value});
};
render() {
return (<b><Dropdown className="dropdownCss" options={this.state.options} onChange={this.quan}/></b>);
}
}
```

Comment: I have pasted the code I tried try it.It should work

Answer (score 1):

I only did a little refactoring to the code. The main change is in how `Dropdown` handles change. When you pass in a function to `handleChange`, `Dropdown` calls the function internally and passes the selected object to it, so you all you needed to do was create a handler method that has one parameter which you'll use to update the state. I also set an initial state for value. Here's is a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/4qz7n0okyw

```
import React,  { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";

const options = [
  { value: "one", label: "One" },
  { value: "two", label: "Two", className: "myOptionClassName" }
];

class WebDashboardPage extends Component {
  state = {
    value: {}
  };

  quan = value => {
    console.log("Option selected:", value);
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Dropdown
          className="dropdownCss"
          options={options}
          onChange={this.quan}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default WebDashboardPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to 
`onChange={this.quan}`, also in the initial state you should state your this.state.value

```
this.state = {
 value: ''
}
```

also try to learn it on html element, not on jsx

Comment: It's not working same error is showing
any other solution